# Turn off devise confirmations but still send email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So what I want to do is basically turn email confirmations into a boolean field in the user database, like it's not required but it will still send out the confirmation mail every once and a while until the user confirms, and on the website you can use if user_confirmed? and such.

Comment: I'm also interested in this - I would call this "optional confirmation".  The desired base functionality would be to send confirmation email, but still allow login.

Answer (score 0):

```
* +allow_unconfirmed_access_for+:
```

will allow the user to log in without being confirmed. If this can be "hotwired" open, or set to a very large number, that would satisfy the requirement.

Sending periodic reminder emails will require setting up a cron job and testing .user_confirmed?

Comment: do you know how to disable sending the confirmation email (and disable the confirmation process) on model basis?